# SignalR 2.1.0: The connection has not been established

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a ASP.NET Web Application with a simple HTML page and some JavaScript to communicate via SignalR. That works fine.
Now I'm trying to call a method on the Hub from another project (in the same solution) and by using the .NET Signalr Client Api:

```
        var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:32986/");
        var hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MessageHub");
        connection.Start();
        hub.Invoke("SendMessage", "", "");
```

The last line causes `InvalidOperationException: The connection has not been established.` But I am able to connect to the hub from my JavaScript code.

How can I connect to the Hub by using C# code?

**UPDATE**

The moment after writing this post, I tried to add `.Wait()` and it worked!
So this will do:

```
        var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:32986/");
        var hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MessageHub");
        connection.Start().Wait();
        hub.Invoke("SendMessage", "", "");
```

Comment: Much thanks! adding the .Wait() worked for me as well. I'm hosting a Hub in a Windows service that also needs a client reference to the hub so it cal call methods in the hub (based on a timer in the service). Same code to create the client reference and also got same 'Connection has not bee established' error until I added .Wait() to the Start() method. Funny because I was working from an example that didn't use the .Wait() yet worked OK. Probably just some kind of timing difference between the two apps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`HubConnection.Start` returns a `Task` that needs to complete before you can invoke a method.

The two ways to do this are to use await if you are in an async method, or to use `Task.Wait()` if you are in a non-async method:

```
public async Task StartConnection()
{
    var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:32986/");
    var hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MessageHub");
    await connection.Start();
    await hub.Invoke("SendMessage", "", "");
    // ...
}

// or

public void StartConnection()
{
    var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:32986/");
    var hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MessageHub");
    connection.Start().Wait();
    hub.Invoke("SendMessage", "", "").Wait();
    // ...
}
```

The "How to establish a connection" section of the [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide for the .NET client.](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) goes into even more detail.

Comment: Third option: `ContinueWith`.  This is essentially the way it's done at the client side, so it's adds a bit of consistency between JS and C# usages.